Smart contract is compiled but not deployed to ganache
I am developing a DAO Dapp, but when I run truffle migrate --reset, the contract compiles but does not get deployed to Ganache. There are no deployment details shown in the console, and the contract is unable to identify the deployed network address, although it recognizes the chain ID.
Could any Web3 enthusiasts help me out with this problem?

Please provide a small project that we could use to reproduce the problem. In any case
Truffle has been deprecated last year. I'll suggest to consider migrating to another tool that is maintained.
